# Which is better for performance in these simple examples?

Tags: c#

```
private bool _invalidated
public void Invalidate()
{
    _invalidated = true;
}
```

or

```
public void Invalidate()
{
    if(!_invalidated)
    {
        _invalidated = true;
    }
}
```

Which would be faster?

This will be called many many times.

Comment: How often will it be called?

Comment: This reeks of premature optimization.

Comment: Just make a benchmark and try it. It's the only way to be sure. (My guess is both would be jitted the same, but I may be wrong). Whatever the result, `_invalidated = false` is easier to read and the difference must be negligible...

Comment: Does it matter when you can invoke it 100 millions times per soconds.

Comment: Never underestimate readability.

Comment: I'll just mention that ReSharper flags the second version and tells you to use the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is less instructions, and contains no conditional, so it's preferable. However, the second would probably be optimized away by a sufficiently smart compiler / JITer.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas says, it depends. And as I4V says, paraphrased, it doesn't matter.

I would go for the first, less code and prettier(of course subjective).